# How to pass user input data between componenets in angular2?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Here's my code, I want to send username input value from login component to home component.I want my username to be updated in constructor so that i can access it in home page. How do I assign updated username in constructor?

login.ts

```
import {Component, Input,Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'fountain-tech',
  template: require('./login.html')
})

@Injectable()
export class loginComponent {
       username :any;
constructor(){
this.username  =  username;
}
buttonName:string;
```

home.ts

```
import {loginComponent} from '../login/login'

@Component({
  selector: 'fountain-tech',
  template: require('./home.html')
})
export class HomeComponent {

constructor(public login:loginComponent){
 console.log(this.login.username);
}
```

I don't get username, it prints undefined in console. There is no problem with provider

Comment: How are loginComponent and HomeComponent related? Are they siblings, parent/child, no specific relation? Please add the markup that shows how and where you use them

Comment: I guess your are using `IONIC framework` also. isn't that right?

Comment: No I am not using ionic.

Comment: Usually the right way to do this is by saving the `username` (and possibly the `token` returned from your `auth service` if you have one) in a cookie or the localStorage of the browser, upon a successful login attempt inside the `LoginComponent`. After that you'll be able to retrieve the `username` from the storage inside the constructor of `HomeComponent` or any other component at any time as long as the storage is not cleared.

Comment: yes it works with local storage, it skips the part of using service and DI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Input()` in your login.ts and then inject it to your home like this:

**login.ts**

```
Input() username: any;
```

and then you can use

```
<app-home [data]="username"></app-home>
```

you should have `data:any;` in your home.ts

UPDATE

If you want to use service, you can create a new service for example login.service.ts and define a new variable `username:any;`.

now in your login.ts

```
constructor(private _username:LoginService)
{}

submit(){
  this._username.username = this.username;
}
```

and in your home.ts constructor

```
constructor(private _username:LoginService)
{
  myUsername = this._username.username
}
```

Comment: @omkar You can use service to do this,so when you set the username in the login.ts the username will be updated in the service, and when you are in home.ts you will get the value from the service after updated

Comment: thanks for replying , i tried with local storage and it worked fine.I will try out ur solution too and revert soon